# Testing a multitude of data asynchronously in Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I need to loop through a list of emails and to check that they validate. If one fails to validate, I throw an error to let Mocha know about it.

```
it('validates valid email addresses', function (done) {
  [
    'oliverash@me.com',
    'oliver.ash@me.com',
    'oliver-ash@me.com',
    'oliver+ash@me.com',
    'oliver\'s-email@me.com'
  ].forEach(function (value) {
    user.email = value

    user.validate(function (err) {
      // Failed to validate, throw an error
      if (err) {
        throw new Error()
      }
    })
  })

  // All documents validated, so call `done`
  done()
})
```

This code doesn't seem to work right, however – only the last email in the array will invalidate if it is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)* utility library to simplify do an asynchronous loop.

```
it('validates valid email addresses', function (done) {
  async.forEach([
    'oliverash@me.com',
    'oliver.ash@me.com',
    'oliver-ash@me.com',
    'oliver+ash@me.com',
    'oliver\'s-email@me.com'
  ], 
  function (value, callback) {
    user.email = value
    user.validate(callback)
  },
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error()
    }
    done()
  })
})
```

The first function is called on each element in the array, it takes two arguments: the item from the array, and a callback function. If the callback receives an error, it immediately goes stops iterating. Once all of the items in the array are done (or any of them return an error), the final function is called. In this example it'll either throw an error or run the Mocha done function.

The [readme for async](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach) has a good explanation of how the forEach function works.

Comment: This looks promising, although I still have the problem of only the last email address counting. If any of the others are invalid, the test will still pass. The validation itself is fine, it's the test that's the problem.

Comment: It turns out, this is because I don't want the loop iterations to happen in parallel. I need them to happen one after the other, I think. This is because `user.email = value` is equating to the last item in the array, if that makes sense.

Comment: If it's for unit testing only, you can replace `forEach` by `forEachSeries` to make everything synchronous and avoid getting `user.email` with the last email always.

Comment: Yes! That's perfect. Thank you. I take it I still need to use `async`?

Comment: Obviously. `forEachSeries` is part of `async`. Moreover, `async` is a great librairy that you should use when dealing with asynchronous code, will save you A LOT of headaches :)

Comment: You can use forEachSeries if you like, but the test should work regardless. If any of the values returns an error in the validation function, the final callback will be called with an error. If and only if all of them return without an error will the final callback be called without an error (and run the done function).

Comment: Really? That doesn't appear to be the case. [Here's my code](https://gist.github.com/4697762#file-user-js-L93). The selected line contains an invalid email but it does not cause the test to fail. If I change `forEach` to `forEachSeries`, then it does cause the test to fail.

Comment: @matthewtole – The trouble is that, because the loop runs in parallel, by time `validate` gets to work, `user.email` is always the last email in the list. I can confirm this if I just `console.log(user.email)` inside of `user.validate` – it will give me 5 of the same email addresses (the last one in the array).

Comment: Updated link to code: https://gist.github.com/4697762/6512dffb047310d0ad1870e73143fc404b5ee02e#file-user-js-L93

Comment: Ah. That's because you're using the same object for each validation. The value of `user.email` is being changed before it can be validated. You can either use `forEachSeries` or you can create a new User object for each validation. [See this Gist](https://gist.github.com/4698265) for what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

If your `user.validate` function is asynchronous, your forEach call will not wait the callback call of `user.validate`.

Which mean that your forEach function will end before `user.validate` calls all callbacks and will call `done()` before every validation has ended.

You should use all parameters of `forEach` function and call `done()` in the `user.validate` callback. I will add one count variable to count callback called and know when I need to call `done()` function.

```
it('validates valid email addresses', function (done) {
  var count = 0;     // count variable
  [
    'oliverash@me.com',
    'oliver.ash@me.com',
    'oliver-ash@me.com',
    'oliver+ash@me.com',
    'oliver\'s-email@me.com'
  ].forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    user.email = value;

    user.validate(function (err) {
      ++count;      // Callback called, we add +1 to count.
      if (err) {
        throw new Error();
      }
      // Check if all callbacks have been called and call done if true.
      if (count === array.length)
        done();
    });

  });

})
```

This should work better. I didn't tested it, but it should work.

PS: Please do not forget semicolons. It can brings you undefined behavior in some cases and it's a bad habbits to not put them (we are programmers !).

**EDIT - 08/06/13**: Just read something about semicolons in Javascript and remembered about this thread, this is why you should put semicolons in your code : http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#core.semicolon

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Here, `done` will still call even if an error has been thrown in an earlier iteration, meaning the test will always pass. I guess I'll have to set another flag to circumvent that? Also I'm using `index` instead of `count` – bit more efficient.

Comment: P.S. no semicolon is my choice of coding style. Perfectly fine to do in JS.

Comment: Well, you get the point. I do not use index, because sometimes, the callback for index `4` will be called before callback for index `0`, meaning that you will get the same problem. You can't know when a callback is going to be called as well as if they will be called in the right order. In fact, `done()` will be called only if no callback has throw a `new Error()` because we check it before trying to call `done ()`. If a `new Error()` is thrown, the execution stop and Mocha, with `it()` call, will catch the error and end the test. Else, you call `done()` adn everything is fine !

Comment: Hmm, okay. Then how come this test passes? It only seems to catch the validation error if the invalid email is the last one in the array. https://gist.github.com/4697762/83e4ad0c71c8301dc627354f7cefd41fa51b8fb3#file-user-js-L83